# Creating a cross-browser editable iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

I have been working on an HTML editor using an editable iframe that allows users to create and edit content. I have found that the HTML generated within the iframe varies depending upon the browser being used. For example, in IE and Opera, blocks of text are surrounded by `<p>` tags;

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

In Firefox, blocks of texts end with `<br>` tags;

```
Hello world!<br>
```

And in Safari and Chrome, blocks of text are surrounded by `<div>` tags;

```
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

This can be problematic if a user creates content in one browser and tries to edit it in another and can over time lead to inconsistencies in the HTML code.

I have found that some HTML editors can produce the same format of HTML regardless of the browser being used. For example, in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo), blocks of text are always surrounded by `<p>` tags, allowing the HTML to be cleanly created and edited in any browser.

**Is there a way of forcing the iframe to use a specific set of HTML tags, mainly creating only `<p>` tags when someone creates a new paragraph or block of text regardless of browser?** Can anyone offer me any tips, samples of code, or solutions to my problem? I know I could use an existing HTML editor, but it is only this particular aspect that I am interested in.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple way. CKEditor and the like do it by adding lots of custom event handling. I would suggest looking at their source code for inspiration.

There is a [specification for HTML Editing](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html) that has reached a reasonable level of completion but as far as I can tell there has been little effort so far by the browser developers to implement it.

Comment: Do you know any code snippets online that could help me create such as event handler? So far the best I could come up with captures keyboard input and inserts blank paragraph tags when the enter key has been pressed.

Comment: None that I'd recommend. It's a harder problem than it looks, from my memory of trying to solve it myself once.